# Combinations with constraints find a repartitions that goes from low to high

Tags: python, algorithm, generator, combinations, dynamically-generated

I have a project where I need to find an algorithm that can solve the following problem:

Having three list of items :

```
A = [1,2,3,4,5]
B = [1,2,3,4,5]
C = [1,2,3,4,5]
```

With python I can find all unique combinations via this line of code:

```
allCombinations = list(set(product(A,B,C)))
```

But now i need to get from all of those combinations, the combinations that follow a pretty linear repartition.

for example, there are 125 unique combinations, and now I want 50 combinations where A1 B1 C1 appear less than A2 B2 C2 ... (if it can be almost linear, it will be perfect)

I have no idea how to solve this kind of problem, how can I select the best combinations that correspond to my thinking.

I can do it handly with 125 combinations, but for more it's too difficult.

Thanks

#Edit

I'll remake the example here.

```
A=[1,2] 
B=[1,2] 
C=[1,2]
```

the combinations from this list are

```
(1,1,1) (1,2,1) (1,2,2) (1,1,2) (2,1,1) (2,1,2) (2,2,1) (2,2,2)
```

If i need to select 3 combinations, i will choose (2,2,2) (1,2,2) (2,2,1) because i want to make 1 for A,B,C list fewer than 2 from A,B,C.

The goal is to produce rarity, A,B,C represents three list of items. Make the first item of the three list more rare than the second.

And i want to do it for a lot of items.

Comment: `product()` does what ? does is need an `import` ?

Comment: *"where A1 B1 C1 appear less than A2 B2 C2"*: you expect letters in the output? It would be good if you gave more concrete examples of what you mean with *"pretty linear repartition"*.

Comment: @p._phidot_ yes it's an import `from itertools import product`

Comment: @trincot Sorry for my poor english, in the output i want just combinations of number for example  (1,2,3) , (1,3,4) ... knowing that for this example there will be 125 unique combinations, i want to choose combinations where there are fewer 1 from A,B,C list, and fewer combinations that contains 2 from A,B,C . .. i'll remake an example that is more explicite

Comment: @trincot I can't edit my post as i'm new on Stackoverflow. I'll remake the example here.  `A = [1,2] B=[1,2] C=[1,2]` the combinations are ` (1,1,1) (1,2,1) (1,2,2) (1,1,2) (2,1,1) (2,1,2) (2,2,1) (2,2,2) ` if i need to select 3 combinations, i will choose `(2,2,2) (1,2,2) (2,2,1)` because i want to make 1 for A,B,C list fewer than 2 from A,B,C. The goal is to produce rarity, A,B,C represents three list of items.

Comment: I don't understand why (2,2,2) is somehow more linear than (1,1,1). Please explain in mathematical terms what you want to optimise.

Comment: (imho) I don't think OP meant linear mathematically.. I think OP meant "count of 1 in the list" < "count of 2 in the list"

Comment: @luke , try scan through `allCombinations` (using a for loop). count each 1,2,3 in one a array. If "count of 1" < "count of 2" , append/save the array... that should do.

Comment: @trincot I'm not good in english, that's maybe the reason why it's difficult to understand the problem. The goal is to find combinations that make small number appear less than high number, that's why i talk about linear.

Comment: Are A, B, and C always the same size? Are there always 3 lists? Are they always sorted? Is it always true that A == B == C?

Comment: @trincot A, B and C can have different size. It can be more than 3 list. The number in the list is not soo important it can be whatever (string ...). A is not equal to B neither to C, A !== B !== C.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your problem is a little under-specified, so you have a choice to make as to how exactly you want to weight your combinations.

One possibility is to choose random combinations, but with a weight of `i*j*k` attributed to combination `[A[i],B[j],C[k]]`. So for instance, combination `[A2,B2,C2]` will be 8 times more likely to be chosen as combination `[A1,B1,C1]`.

We can use `random.sample` to sample with weights: https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.sample

**Python 3.9:**

```py
import itertools  # product
import random     # sample

def sampleCombinations(A, B, C, k):
  allCombinations = list(itertools.product(enumerate(A), enumerate(B), enumerate(C)))
  weights = [(i+1) * (j+1) * (k+1) for (i,_), (j,_), (k,_) in allCombinations]
  sampled = random.sample(allCombinations, k, counts=weights)
  sampled_clean = [(x,y,z) for (_,x), (_,y), (_,z) in sampled]
  return sampled_clean

print(sampleCombinations(['A1','A2','A3','A4','A5'], ['B1','B2','B3','B4','B5'], ['C1','C2','C3','C4','C5'], 50))

print(sampleCombinations([1, 2], [1, 2], [1, 2], 3))
```

Note the use of `enumerate` to get the indices `i,j,k` that are needed to compute the weights. Then we don't forget to remove the indices in `sampled_clean` before returning the combinations. Also note the weights are computed as `(i+1)*(j+1)*(k+1)` rather than `i*j*k`, because everything is 0-indexed, not 1-indexed.

*Note: the "counts" keyword argument of random.sample is new in python 3.9. Prior to version 3.9, it was necessary to manually duplicate elements in the population to simulate the weights.*

**Python < 3.9:**

```py
import itertools  # product
import random     # sample

def sampleCombinations(A, B, C, k):
  allCombinations = list(itertools.product(enumerate(A), enumerate(B), enumerate(C)))
  weights = [(i+1) * (j+1) * (k+1) for (i,_), (j,_), (k,_) in allCombinations]
  weightedCombinations = [c for c,w in zip(allCombinations, weights) for _ in range(w)]
  sampled = random.sample(weightedCombinations, k)
  sampled_clean = [(x,y,z) for (_,x), (_,y), (_,z) in sampled]
  return sampled_clean

print(sampleCombinations(['A1','A2','A3','A4','A5'], ['B1','B2','B3','B4','B5'], ['C1','C2','C3','C4','C5'], 50))
# [('A3', 'B4', 'C2'), ('A4', 'B4', 'C5'), ('A2', 'B5', 'C5'), ('A4', 'B4', 'C4'), ('A3', 'B1', 'C4'), ('A4', 'B3', 'C3'), ('A4', 'B4', 'C2'), ('A5', 'B3', 'C4'), ('A2', 'B5', 'C3'), ('A5', 'B2', 'C2'), ('A5', 'B4', 'C3'), ('A4', 'B3', 'C1'), ('A3', 'B2', 'C5'), ('A2', 'B5', 'C5'), ('A4', 'B5', 'C5'), ('A5', 'B5', 'C5'), ('A3', 'B4', 'C5'), ('A3', 'B4', 'C5'), ('A5', 'B4', 'C2'), ('A2', 'B3', 'C1'), ('A2', 'B5', 'C2'), ('A3', 'B4', 'C4'), ('A4', 'B5', 'C1'), ('A3', 'B2', 'C2'), ('A4', 'B3', 'C5'), ('A2', 'B3', 'C3'), ('A3', 'B4', 'C1'), ('A5', 'B5', 'C4'), ('A3', 'B5', 'C5'), ('A3', 'B2', 'C5'), ('A5', 'B5', 'C3'), ('A5', 'B5', 'C3'), ('A3', 'B4', 'C4'), ('A4', 'B1', 'C1'), ('A3', 'B3', 'C4'), ('A4', 'B2', 'C5'), ('A5', 'B5', 'C5'), ('A4', 'B4', 'C3'), ('A1', 'B5', 'C3'), ('A4', 'B5', 'C3'), ('A4', 'B4', 'C2'), ('A5', 'B2', 'C2'), ('A5', 'B2', 'C5'), ('A4', 'B3', 'C5'), ('A4', 'B5', 'C1'), ('A4', 'B3', 'C5'), ('A5', 'B5', 'C5'), ('A3', 'B5', 'C3'), ('A5', 'B4', 'C5'), ('A3', 'B1', 'C4')]

print(sampleCombinations([1, 2], [1, 2], [1, 2], 3))
# [(2, 2, 2), (2, 2, 2), (1, 1, 1)]
```

Comment: Good idea for solving my problem. I will consider it, thanks.